# incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am getting this error (memory location varies between runs):

```
q2(4910,0x7fff7a1d4300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdf79c04bd8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

This is the function that crashes:

```
public:
// construct a 'rows X cols' matrix.
SMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    if (rows<1 || cols<1) {
        cout<<"Invalid row/col value(s).";
        exit(-1);
    }
    this->_rows = rows;
    this->_cols = cols;
    this->_vertical = new simpleNode [rows];
    this->_horizontal = new simpleNode [cols];
    if (this->_vertical == NULL || this->_horizontal==NULL) {
        cout<<"Exiting";
        exit(-1);
    }
    initArrays();
}
```

It crashes on this particular line:

```
  this->_horizontal = new simpleNode [cols];
```

The function that calls:

```
int main() {
      SMatrix bigM(500,500);
      bigM.setElement(10,20,17);
      cout <<" bigM - total size in bytes: (implementation depended): "
       << bigM.sizeInBytes() << endl << endl; 

      SMatrix m1(7,10),m2(7,10),m4(10,2),m5(7,2); //Crashes on m4(10,2)
}
```

Other functions that could be relevant:

```
struct simpleNode {
    Node* _next;
};
int _rows; //Number of rows in this SMatrix
int _cols; //Number of columns in this SMatrix
simpleNode * _vertical; //array (simpleNode)
simpleNode * _horizontal;  //array (simpleNode)
/*Initiate the horizontal/vertical arrays to point to null*/
void initArrays() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<this->_rows; i++)
        this->_horizontal[i]._next = NULL;
    for (i=0; i<this->_cols; i++)
        this->_vertical[i]._next = NULL;
}
```

I am on OSX. I compiled with -g and ran it with GDB but *Program exited normally.*
How can I debug this if I don't use XCode? Also a hint on how to fix the problem would be very helpful.

Edit: I'm running the output file and sometimes it runs while others it gives me the error. Seems to be at a random order. Also, the program never fails when I run it on gdb it always exits correctly. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your limits are reversed in your initialization code. You create your arrays like this:

```
this->_vertical = new simpleNode [rows];   // <== uses rows for sizing vertical
this->_horizontal = new simpleNode [cols]; // <== uses cols for sizing horizontal
```

But your initialization does this:

```
for (i=0; i<this->_rows; i++) // <== limit is rows, but you walking horizontal
    this->_horizontal[i]._next = NULL;
for (i=0; i<this->_cols; i++) // <== limit is cols, but you walking vertical
    this->_vertical[i]._next = NULL;
```

Unless `rows` and `cols` are the same value, this code invokes *undefined behavior*. Fix this by using the same values as you sized your allocation with

```
for (i=0; i<this->_rows; i++)
    this->_vertical[i]._next = NULL;
for (i=0; i<this->_cols; i++)
    this->_horizontal[i]._next = NULL;
```

Honestly a much better approach would use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) containers such as `std::vector<>`, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Best of luck, and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in the debugger, you should look at the memory location `0x7fff7a1d4300` and see what's there. The data in memory may be helpful in figuring out what's going wrong.

What's happening is one of the following:

1. you are freeing an object twice,
2. you are freeing a pointer that was never allocated
3. you are writing through an invalid pointer which previously pointed to an object which was already freed

I think what happens is No.3.

My answer is based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840671/malloc-error-for-object-0x208a7614-incorrect-checksum-for-freed-object-o) answer.

---

A relevant discussion lies [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/46305/).

---

Relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb) about gdb.

Comment: I am not in the debugger.

Comment: But you used `-g` flag. @Airwavezx

Comment: Can you refer me to how to look at a memory location?

Comment: The memory location varies between different failures. What value should I watch in gdb? Also, the program never fails when I run it on gdb it always exits correctly. Why is this happening?

Comment: I do not know to say more.