# m4a audio files not playing on iOS 9

Tags: core-audio, ios9, audiounit, m4a

I have an audio related app that has multichannel mixer to play m4a files at a time.
I'm using  the AudioToolBox framework to stream audio, but on iOS9 the framework throws me exception in mixer rendering callback where i am streaming the audio files.

Interestingly apps compiled with the iOS9 SDK continue to stream the same file perfectly on iOS7/8 devices, but not iOS9.
Now i can't figure out if Apple broke something in iOS9, or we have the files encoded wrong on our end, but they play just fine on both iOS 7/8 but not 9.

Exception:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fac74056e08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

It works for all other formats does not give any exception or any kind of memory errors but does not work for m4a format which is very surprising.

Here is a code to load files which works for wav,aif etc formats but not for m4a:

```
- (void)loadFiles{

    AVAudioFormat *clientFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32
                                                                   sampleRate:kGraphSampleRate
                                                                     channels:1
                                                                  interleaved:NO];
    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles && i < maxBufs; i++)  {

        ExtAudioFileRef xafref = 0;

        // open one of the two source files
        OSStatus result = ExtAudioFileOpenURL(sourceURL[i], &xafref);
        if (result || !xafref) {break; }

        // get the file data format, this represents the file's actual data format
        AudioStreamBasicDescription fileFormat;
        UInt32 propSize = sizeof(fileFormat);

        result = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(xafref, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &propSize, &fileFormat);
        if (result) { break; }

        // set the client format - this is the format we want back from ExtAudioFile and corresponds to the format
        // we will be providing to the input callback of the mixer, therefore the data type must be the same

        double rateRatio = kGraphSampleRate / fileFormat.mSampleRate;

        propSize = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
        result = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(xafref, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, propSize, clientFormat.streamDescription);
        if (result) { break; }

        // get the file's length in sample frames
        UInt64 numFrames = 0;
        propSize = sizeof(numFrames);
        result = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(xafref, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &propSize, &numFrames);
        if (result) { break; }

        if(i==metronomeBusIndex)
            numFrames = (numFrames+6484)*4;
        //numFrames = (numFrames * rateRatio); // account for any sample rate conversion
        numFrames *= rateRatio;


        // set up our buffer
        mSoundBuffer[i].numFrames = (UInt32)numFrames;
        mSoundBuffer[i].asbd = *(clientFormat.streamDescription);

        UInt32 samples = (UInt32)numFrames * mSoundBuffer[i].asbd.mChannelsPerFrame;
        mSoundBuffer[i].data = (Float32 *)calloc(samples, sizeof(Float32));
        mSoundBuffer[i].sampleNum = 0;

        // set up a AudioBufferList to read data into
        AudioBufferList bufList;
        bufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        bufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
        bufList.mBuffers[0].mData = mSoundBuffer[i].data;
        bufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = samples * sizeof(Float32);

        // perform a synchronous sequential read of the audio data out of the file into our allocated data buffer
        UInt32 numPackets = (UInt32)numFrames;

        result = ExtAudioFileRead(xafref, &numPackets, &bufList);
        if (result) {
            free(mSoundBuffer[i].data);
            mSoundBuffer[i].data = 0;
        }

        // close the file and dispose the ExtAudioFileRef
        ExtAudioFileDispose(xafref);
    }

    // [clientFormat release];
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, how do i go about debugging the issue?
Do we need to re-encode our files in some specific way?

Comment: Please be more concrete on your problem. What is the exception about? What functions do you rely on? Have you considered the [iOS 9 Diff](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/AudioToolbox.html)?

Comment: Michael could you look into it now or you need more concrete things? And yes I did check iOS9 Diff...could not find anything out of it which will help me to find solution.

Comment: You do some `if (result) { break; }`; which checks are fine and which one fails? Where is the exception thrown? What does the [debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22417528/1864294) tell us?

Comment: Excption is thrown at this line:  ExtAudioFileDispose(xafref);                                   and debugger gives this : malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe03c804c08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on iOS 9.1.beta3 yesterday and things seem to be back to normal.

Try it out. Let us know if it works out for you too.