# C++ function with pointer argument

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, memory-management

I am writing a C++ program that outputs data to a file, generates a **python** script and calls `pyplot` to make the plotting.

However, when I pass the arguments in terms of the pointers, it can be compiled properly, but cannot run.  It returns error.  When I use **Xcode debug mode** and execute it step by step, it gives correct result by chance but not always.  Sometimes it also returns an error.

I doubt that it might be caused by some **memory allocation** problem, but I cannot identify what is exactly the problem.

My codes are as following:

1) main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "PyCPlot.h"

using namespace std;

double pi = 3.1415926;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int nline = 100;

    double * np_list = new double(nline);
    double * pack_fraction_np = new double (nline);

    for (int i=0; i<nline; i++){
        np_list[i] = double(i)/double(nline)*2*pi;
        pack_fraction_np[i] = cos(np_list[i]);
    }

    PyCPlot_data_fout("RandomPacking", nline, np_list, pack_fraction_np);
    PyCPlot_pythonscript("RandomPacking", "Random Packing");
    PyCPlot_pyplot("RandomPacking", "Random Packing");

    return 0;
}
```

2) head file

```
#ifndef PyCPlot_h
#define PyCPlot_h

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int PyCPlot_data_fout(string datafilename, int nline, double * x, double *y){
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(datafilename+".txt");
    fout << nline << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<nline; i++){
        fout << x[i] << "  " << y[i] << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}

int PyCPlot_pythonscript(string datafilename, string plttitle){

    string strhead = "import numpy as np\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n";
    string strpltfig = "plt.figure()\n";
    string strpltplt = "plt.plot(xlist, ylist)\n";
    string strplttit = "plt.title('"+plttitle+"')\n";
    string strpltshw = "plt.show()\n";

    string strfileopen ="f = open('"+datafilename+".txt', 'r')\n";
    string strreadline ="size = map(int, f.readline().split())\n";
    string strpltlist ="xlist = np.zeros((size))\nylist = np.zeros((size))\n";
    string strfor = "for i in range(size[0]):\n    xlist[i], ylist[i] = map(float, f.readline().split())\n";

    ofstream pyout;
    pyout.open("PyCPlot_"+datafilename+".py");
    pyout << strhead << strfileopen << strreadline << strpltlist << strfor;
    pyout << strpltfig << strpltplt << strplttit << strpltshw;
    pyout.close();
    return 0;
}

int PyCPlot_pyplot(string datafilename, string plttitle){

    string strsystemsh ="source ~/.bashrc; python PyCPlot_"+datafilename+".py";
    system(strsystemsh.c_str());

    return 0;
}

#endif /* PyCPlot_h */
```

When it is ran, I get below error message

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1002002e8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Comment: are you trying to build for ios, may be have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840671/malloc-error-incorrect-checksum-for-freed-object-object-was-probably-mod

Comment: Mainly your code doesnt see any free call, can you please mention your platform

Comment: [OT]: You should avoid to use `using namespace std;` especially in header.

Comment: [OT]: you should mark `inline` the functions defined in header to be able to include your header in several cpp files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass an array, so pass an actual array which can be sized at runtime (`std::vector`), not some random pointer that hopefully will be pointing to the first element of an array (and in this case, it doesn't)

Your mistake is using `new double(x)` instead of `new double[x]`. The former allocates a single `double` with a value equal to `x`, and the latter allocates an array of `double` of size `x` and returns a pointer to the first element, but, as I've said, you wouldn't have that problem at all had you actually used `std::vector` and not dabbled with pointers like the early 90s style (not to mention, you wouldn't have a memory leak had you used `std::vector`).

Comment: There are reasons to avoid `vector`, but even then you should use a `unique_ptr<T[]>` or something. Most of those reasons are performance overhead, which is completely dwarfed by using Python.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a few things which are not right or seem strange.

The code `new double(nline)` will allocate a single double with the value of `nline`, which doesn't seem what you intend.
It looks like you intend to dynamically allocate an array of *double*. Actually from the code you've shown there's no reason you can't do a simple array as the size is known at compile time.

This code below:

```
double * np_list = new double(nline);
double * pack_fraction_np = new double (nline);
```

Could be replaced with:

```
double np_list[nline];
double pack_fraction_np[nline];
```

Comment: Best declaring `nline` as `constexpr`

Comment: That or `std::array<double, nline>` would be best *if* it’s going to stay a compile-time constant, but if it was just set that way for debugging it doesn’t really help.

Comment: Note that since `nline` is a function parameter, using `double np_list[nline];` relies on a non-standard gcc extension (VLAs). `std::vector<double> np_list(nline);` will work reliably across all standard compliant C++ compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines allocate a single double for `np_list` and `pack_fraction_np`:

```
double * np_list = new double(nline);
double * pack_fraction_np = new double (nline);
```

As a result, when you will enter your loop, you will write data to invalid memory blocks. You have to use square brackets to define an array (I do not get any error; using clang++).

Consider to use the `std::vector`class. Here is an example (your example) with `std::pair` of `double` nested in a `std::vector`:

### PyCPlot.h

```
#ifndef PyCPlot_h
#define PyCPlot_h

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int PyCPlot_data_fout(string datafilename, std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& v){
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(datafilename+".txt");
    fout << v.size() << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++){
        fout << v[i].first << "  " << v[i].second << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}

int PyCPlot_pythonscript(string datafilename, string plttitle){

    string strhead = "import numpy as np\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n";
    string strpltfig = "plt.figure()\n";
    string strpltplt = "plt.plot(xlist, ylist)\n";
    string strplttit = "plt.title('"+plttitle+"')\n";
    string strpltshw = "plt.show()\n";

    string strfileopen ="f = open('"+datafilename+".txt', 'r')\n";
    string strreadline ="size = map(int, f.readline().split())\n";
    string strpltlist ="xlist = np.zeros((size))\nylist = np.zeros((size))\n";
    string strfor = "for i in range(size[0]):\n    xlist[i], ylist[i] = map(float, f.readline().split())\n";

    ofstream pyout;
    pyout.open("PyCPlot_"+datafilename+".py");
    pyout << strhead << strfileopen << strreadline << strpltlist << strfor;
    pyout << strpltfig << strpltplt << strplttit << strpltshw;
    pyout.close();
    return 0;
}

int PyCPlot_pyplot(string datafilename, string plttitle){

    string strsystemsh ="source ~/.bashrc; python PyCPlot_"+datafilename+".py";
    system(strsystemsh.c_str());

    return 0;
}

#endif /* PyCPlot_h */
```

### PyCPlot.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "PyCPlot.h"

using namespace std;

double pi = 3.1415926;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int nline = 100;
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> v;
    v.reserve(nline);

    double a;
    for (int i=0; i < nline; i++){
        a = double(i)/double(nline)*2*pi;
        v.push_back(std::make_pair(a, cos(a)));
    }

    PyCPlot_data_fout("RandomPacking", v);
    PyCPlot_pythonscript("RandomPacking", "Random Packing");
    PyCPlot_pyplot("RandomPacking", "Random Packing");

    return 0;
}
```